# Selenium WebDriver: not able to find button "Add to cart" for Amazon.com

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I have tried couple of things but still not able to find the button. It's not on frame.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//input[@id='add-to-cart-button'")).click();

driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//input[@id='add-to-cart-button' and 
@name='submit.add-to-cart']")).click();

driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#add-to-cart-button")).click();
```

Tried adding `WebDriverWait`

```
WebDriverWait wait= new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
  element=wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(driver.findElement(By.xpath(XPATH_ADD_TO_CART))));
```

Here is the relevant `html`:

```
<input id="add-to-cart-button" 
  name="submit.add-to-cart" 
  title="Add to Shopping Cart" 
  data-hover="Select 
    <b>__dims__</b> from the left<br> to add to Shopping Cart" 
  class="a-button-input" 
  type="submit" 
  value="Add to Cart" 
  aria-labelledby="submit.add-to-cart-announce">
```

Please help, what am i missing here?TIA

Comment: Can you post some `html`? The selectors you are trying wouldn't work for the add to cart button I'm looking at, but I'm pretty sure you're on some other page, and I can't guess where that is.

Comment: <input id="add-to-cart-button" name="submit.add-to-cart" title="Add to Shopping Cart" data-hover="Select <b>__dims__</b> from the left<br> to add to Shopping Cart" class="a-button-input" type="submit" value="Add to Cart" aria-labelledby="submit.add-to-cart-announce">

Comment: i tries finding it by using $("#add-to-cart-button") in chrome's dev tool. it returned me the above tag.

Comment: My guess is there is some kind of inner or outer element you actually want to click. Do you get an error message? Or does it just not click?

Comment: @Ritu try this xpath "//*[@id='buybox']//span[contains(text(),'Add to Cart')]".

Comment: Try this `By.cssSelector("#submit\.add-to-cart .a-button-inner")` or the xpath equivalent `By.xPath(".//*[@id='submit.add-to-cart']//*[@class='a-button-inner']")` I think it's the `span` you actually want to click. If it works let me know and I'll post the answer

Comment: still not working."org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element"

Comment: @Ritu Your button might be different, since I don't know what page you're on. Try selecting the `span` that contains that `input` you pasted in the comments

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/0345391802 on this page, i am trying to select quantity and then click the "Add to cart" button.

Comment: @Ritu are you sure you're using the driver instance that is attached to that page? and you're actually on this page when calling it? There is nothing wrong with most of the suggestions I've seen on this question for grabbing this element

Comment: I was working with the exception thrown but it was a priority issue.Its working now. Thank you all for helping!

Answer (score 0):

you're missing the closing `]` bracket.

change

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//input[@id='add-to-cart-button'")).click();
```

to

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//input[@id='add-to-cart-button']")).click();
```

Comment: @Ritu wow, i just copied your code and changed it without testing it, but i realized you are missing a closing `]` in your XPATH. i just modified my answer, tested it, and it works for me

Comment: i made mistake while copying it. Still have this : org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":".//input[@id='add-to-cart-button']"}

Comment: @Ritu weird. i don't seem to be having a problem on my end. have you tried returning the page source as selenium sees it, and checking to see if the element is in fact in there? there's a chance selenium may not be seeing the element in source even though you may see it when navigating manually

Comment: i tried driver.getPageSource().contains("add-to-cart-button") it returns false.

Comment: @Ritu you may have to dump out the page source, manually look through it, and see what you find. if you're able to put the code in a gist or on pastebin and provide a link, i can help look.

Comment: I was working with the exception thrown but it was a priority issue. Thank you for helping!

Comment: Is that issue fixed yet?

Answer (score 0):

Python 2.7

By xpath:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@class='a-button-input']").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='add-to-cart-button']").click()
```

And easiest way:

```
driver.find_element_by_id('add-to-cart-button')
```

Comment: I was working with the exception thrown but it was a priority issue. Thank you for helping!